# How can I filter column for MAX, MIN and limit each output to 1 each using alphabetically first CITY?

Tags: sql

**Goal:**

1. Find MAX AND MIN "length" for CITY column
2. Pick 1 result for MAX AND 1 for MIN.
3. If we have more than 1 MAX or MIN output, then pick 1 CITY with highest Alphabetical order (ie. Closest to "A")

**Issue:**
I can't seem to filter and narrow down my results alphabetically to a single CITY with MAX and MIN LENGTH(CITY). Could someone advise on how best could I perform this action effectively without hardcoding the "CITY='Amo'" in the query below?

**[Table Name: STATION - Strcuture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naoxd.jpg)**

Incomplete Solution #1:

```sql
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE (
    LENGTH(CITY) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
    OR LENGTH(CITY) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
    )
ORDER BY CITY ASC
;
```

OUTPUT:

```sql
Amo 3 
Lee 3 
Marine On Saint Croix 21 
Roy 3
```

Incomplete Solution #2:

```sql
SELECT CITY ASC, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
UNION ALL
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Roy 3 
Amo 3 
Lee 3 
Marine On Saint Croix 21
```

Incompetent Solution:

```sql
SELECT CITY ASC, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
UNION ALL
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(CITY)) FROM STATION)
AND CITY = 'Amo' 
;
```

**CORRECT** OUTPUT:

```sql
Amo 3 
Marine On Saint Croix 21
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? This is super-easy in Oracle with `KEEP FIRST/LAST`, but not too difficult in other DBMS with `ROW_NUMBER` either.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify any RDBMS however using analytic functions (supported by most popular RDBMS) you could do something like:

```
with c as (
    select *,
      Row_Number() over(order by Length(city),city) MinCity,
      Row_Number() over(order by Length(city) desc,city) MaxCity
    from Station
)
select City, Len(city) 
from c
where MinCity = 1 or MaxCity = 1
order by City
```